# Alter Table Add Column with Default value And FK, that Value no existing in FK Reference Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, alter-table

This is My Tables :

**Member** : Id, ....

**Product**: Id, ....

My `Member` Table have some values none if them with Id = 0 and I don't want to add any member with Id = 0, So I try to run this Script:

```
ALTER TABLE [Product]
ADD [Member_Id] BIGINT  NOT NULL  DEFAULT(0),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Member] FOREIGN KEY ([Member_Id]) REFERENCES [Member];
```

So There is an Error :

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Product_Member".
```

So I try this one:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Member] ON
INSERT INTO [Member] ([Id]) VALUES  (0);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Member] OFF

ALTER TABLE [Product]
ADD [Member_Id] BIGINT  NOT NULL  DEFAULT(0),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Member] FOREIGN KEY ([Member_Id]) REFERENCES [Member];

DELETE FROM [Member] WHERE [Member].[Id] = 0;
```

Then The new Error is:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Product_Member".
```

If I try to create all Tables again, every thing will be OK of course with lost my Data  so need to get backup, create tables and restore data. So Is there any way to alter Table with this situation? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 14):

The only "value" that you can have in a referencing table, such that the foreign key constraint is not enforced, is `NULL`. Not `0`, or any other magic value.

So the obvious solution is to allow `NULL`s:

```
ALTER TABLE [Product]
ADD [Member_Id] BIGINT  NULL,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Member] FOREIGN KEY ([Member_Id]) REFERENCES [Member];
```

Comment: @Dameien_The_Unbeliever I can't allow `Null` Value

Comment: @Saeid - then you can't have your foreign key constraint.

Comment: @Saeid: if you can't have NULLs, what does a 0 for a value of Product.Member_id mean?  If it means "no member", then a null is appropriate.  It's either that or you have to make a "fake" member with id=0 in order to have the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

your "alter table" is the better way to do this.but at first you are adding the table with value "0" and this is "FOREIGN KEY" but you have not a Member with value "0" so you get error.

the best way as a know is .alter table and then make the true value to the new column and then alter the column and set that to the "FOREIGN KEY"

Comment: you can do a another way.but this is not a good way( use a valid ID for defualt value and after alter table edit the FK )